# Git kraken menu bar is missing

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitkraken

I am using gitkraken for  quite some time but I have noticed that after v2.5 the menu bar(or toolbar)is missing.As a result I can't minimize gitkraken.So if I want to change between gitkraken and another window I have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.There is no close button nor minimize.Here is how it looks like:
[image]

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 budgie remix.Any ideas?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

## For anyone else seeing this:

After contacting GitKraken support they told me that I was in fullscreen mode. So to get out of fullscreen mode one has to press:<kbd>Ctr+Shift+F</kbd>

Comment: Helped me on Windows too!

Comment: Glad that even after 3 years this post managed to help someone

Comment: Three years later, I had the same problem and no memory of having it before, so it helped me again!

Comment: yeah, no idea how this happened to me, but I figured this was a bug in WSLg or Gitkraken and I've been suffering with it for weeks. There ought to be a "exit fullscreen" button so people realize it

Comment: @user3534080 haven't used gitkraken ui lately but if no major revamp has been done it needs a way to be clear to the users